# Phrase for pooling funds with others for a purchase

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

I got an email today from a parent in my son's K class for a party the kids will be hosting for their teacher. Part of the content was this:

> I'm asking for volunteers for the following:
>
> Cut-up Fruit (various types or multiple people could contribute to a small tray)
>
> Cake (again thought few people could contribute to this)

In response, I replied

> Happy to pool in for cake.

I meant that I wanted to pool in with other parents for cake. Did I convey it right? How can I say it in other ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In American English, the most common phrase would be to *[chip in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/chip-in-something)*, as in *I would be happy to chip in for a cake*:

> to give some money, esp. when several people are giving money to pay for something together

An alternative is to *[pitch in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/pitch-in?)*, though in my experience this connotes a contribution of labor rather than capital. Both *chip in* and *pitch in* can also mean to make a small (and perhaps unnecessary) comment, so don't be surprised if a request for others to chip in yields more quips than coins.

Speaking for myself, I would offer to *[go in on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/go-in-on-something) a cake* casually, meaning to join or

> to be involved in an activity that involves others

but which my peers and I often use in the sense of investing in or purchasing something together, like a pizza or a vacation condo.

More formally, I would offer to *[contribute towards](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/contribute) a cake*. That is, I don't intend to purchase the entire thing, in which case I would *contribute a cake*, but rather I want

> to provide money or support to help another person, company, or organization to achieve its goal

Comment: 'Happy to chip in with a cake' would be quite acceptable in British English, though as a metaphor it's a little incongruous here.

Comment: +1 particularly for the distinction between *"I'll chip in"* (I'll contribute money or other "tangibles", and *"I'll pitch in"* (I'll contribute *my own attention and efforts*).

Comment: Almost, but not quite.  Chip in on, go in on, etc. do not necessarily have to do with a **purchase**, which was part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I hear and use ***"happy to chip in"*** more often but given the context of your reply, I'm sure it would be understood - just not common usage, that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I hear pool used in your situation all the time.  We will pool resources for each division for this operations project.  The other parents should understand you.